# The SAS code in terms of "Date"

Tags: sas

I have encountered the code in terms of different ways in SAS to handle 
"Date". However, I do not understand what the last "format" was doing here.
The code is as below.

```
    DATA SASWEEK.Datestest;
  INPUT d1 MMDDYY8. +1 d2 DATE9.;
  * informat does;
  * Can be replaced by an informat statement;
  d1f = d1;
  d2f= d2;
  d3f = d2;
  FORMAT d1f DATE9. d2f WORDDATE. d3f MMDDYY8.; *formats;
  datalines;

01111960 12JAN1960
01011961 01MAR2013
;

PROC PRINt;
RUN;

PROC PRINT;
   FORMAT d1f 9.0 d1 WEEKDATE.;
RUN;
```

Any suggestion and explanation would be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you talking about the last format STATEMENT used with PROC PRINT?

Comment: yes, the last FORMAT statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're referring to the format in the `proc print` as `FORMAT d1f 9.0 d1 WEEKDATE.;`, or the last format in the data step `FORMAT d1f DATE9. d2f WORDDATE. d3f MMDDYY8.;`.

Either way the format just affects the way data is displayed without changing the saved value, which in your case are just numeric as that is what dates are stored as.

SAS dates start from `0` as 1st January 1960, then `1` for 2nd January 1960, and so on. This is why values such as `10` and `11` can be seen in the `proc print` output in the first observation and the second observation follows the same counting sequence.

To reiterate, the format is just affecting the display, not the value.

### Edit

In response to question in comment:

> So based on your explanation, the last "d1f 9.0" was to make d1f from
>   01/11/60 -> "01111960"?

The short answer to your question is "no", an explanation is below.

The first observation for `d1f` is based on the input data `01111960` which is 11th January 1960, and so is day `10` as SAS counts days (as explained in my initial response).

**Variable `d1f` contains the value `10` for the first observation.**

`d1f` has the format `DATE9.` applied to it in the initial data step so the first `proc print` shows `11JAN1960` as the first value of `d1f`.

The second `proc print` has the format `9.0` applied to the value of `d1f`, this instructs SAS to display the value of `d1f` (value is `10`) within 9 columns (with 0 decimal places), this is why you see `10` displayed as the first value of `d1f` in the second `proc print`.

The following data step might also help demonstrate what is happening if you run it after your code and check the log for the results:

```
data _null_;
   set SASWEEK.Datestest;
   put d1f;
   put d1f 9.0;
   put d1f 8.0;
   put d1f 7.0;
   put d1f 6.0;
   put d1f 5.0;
   put d1f 4.0;
   put d1f 3.0;
run;
```

Comment: I was referring to the last FORMAT statement, and I don't understand the "d1f 9.0" was doing here. So based on your explanation, the last "d1f 9.0" was to make d1f from 01/11/60 -> "01111960"?

Comment: See relevant "EDIT" for my response.